# How can I extract records with a column in common?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have two tables with different numbers of columns and rows. I want to find rows using a common column (column B is in common). Here is an example. Could you please help?

`file1.txt`

```
A  B    C   D
a  b    c   d
i  ii  iii iV
*  **   #  ##
```

`file2.txt`

```
E  B  
f  ff 
h  b
g  gg
k  ii
```

output:

```
A  B    C   D  E
a  b    c   d  h
i  ii  iii iV  k
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are doing in a bit more detail please? Why is the last line of `file1` not in the output? And why is column B unchanged in the output while column E is added?

Comment: @terdon: I have two tables including some parameters of many galaxies. Assume table one include "mass" , "name","color" and "distance"  of galaxies and table 2 include  "velocity" and "name". . some galaxies are in common so have same name (column B). Now, I want to have all parameters for this galaxies in one table.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this kind of thing by building a hash / associative array / lookup table e.g. using Awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{B[$2]=$1; next} $2 in B {print $0,B[$2]}' file2.txt file1.txt
A  B    C   D E
a  b    c   d h
i  ii  iii iV k
```

There's also the `join` command - but that requires inputs to be sorted on the common field.

Comment: It works. Thanks, but it doesn't print all columns of file1. could you please tell me how can I print all columns?

Comment: @Negar it *should* print all of the original columns from `file1.txt` (since `$0` in Awk represents the whole record) - is there something additional about your actual files that you forgot to mention?

Comment: @ steeldriver It works right. I made a small mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To add to the answer by @steeldriver, to do it with `sort` and `join`:

```
join -j 2 -o 1.1,0,1.3,1.4,2.1 <(sort -k 2 file1.txt)  <(sort -k 2 file2.txt)
```

- `-j 2` tells `join` which field is the key.
- `-o` gives the order of the fields in the output, where `0` is the common key, and the others are `FILENUM.FIELD`. See `man join` for details.
- `-k 2` tells `sort` which field is the key.
- `<( )` is `bash` process substitution.

Output is:

```
a b c d h
A B C D E
i ii iii iV k
```

Comment: You may find that the column header position can be preserved by enforcing an appropriate locale e.g. `LC_COLLATE=C sort ... `

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström: Thanks. could you please explain about 1.1, 0 ,1.3 ,... since my file1 has 13 columns and this command don't print all of them.

Comment: @Negar: Edited. See `man join` for further details.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/join